# How can I solve System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed in a Blazor server side app with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im having this issue in a **.NET 8 Blazor Server Side app**: *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed.'*

This is a portion of code in **Program.cs**:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EFCoreContext>();

//Set access to repositories
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RoleRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MenuRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RoleMenuRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<FailureRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ParameterRepository>();

//Set access to repositories: CordobaLifeStyle
builder.Services.AddScoped<BlogPostRepository>();
```

This is the **DbContext** called **EFCoreContext**:

```
public class EFCoreContext : DbContext
{
    protected IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Role { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Menu> Menu { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleMenu> RoleMenu { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Failure> Failure { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; }

    //Cordoba LifeStyle
    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPost { get; set; }

    public EFCoreContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("CordobaLifeStyle"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MenuConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleMenuConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new FailureConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ParameterConfiguration());

            //Cordoba LifeStyle
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BlogPostConfiguration());
...
```

This is the repository **MenuRepository** where I make a call to database using **LINQ**. Here is where it throws the mentioned error:

```
    public class MenuRepository : IMenuRepository
    {
        protected readonly EFCoreContext _context;
    
        public MenuRepository(EFCoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<Menu?>> GetAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                 //Here it throws the mentioned error
                 return await _context.Menu.ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                 throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is where I call the repository, in a **Blazor page**:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //Look for saved user in shared component, simulates a session
        User = StateContainer.User == null ? new() : StateContainer.User;

        lstMenuResult = [];
        BlogPost = new();

        if (User != null)
        {
            if (User.UserId != 0)
            {
                //Logged user
                //Here is where I get the error
                List<Menu?> lstMenu = await menuRepository
                                    .GetAll(CancellationToken.None);

                lstMenuResult = await rolemenuRepository
                                    .GetAllByRoleId(User.RoleId, lstMenu);

                lstRole = await roleRepository.GetAll(CancellationToken.None);
                ...
```

All information that you can give is appreciated

Comment: Capture your result from the `ToListAsync` into a variable then return it as a separate statement. I.e. `var results = await _context.Menu.ToListAsync();  return results;` Then note whether the exception happens on the retrieval of the results or as part of when the results are consumed, returned to a caller. If it is happening on the awaited `ToListAsync()` while other calls are suceeding, check for the call to OnInitializedAsync or further up the call chain not being awaited. If it is erroring on the `return results;` then you may be falling foul of lazy loading.

Comment: @StevePy sir, I proved the answer given by Suryateja KONDLA and works! Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Scope of the DbContext by adding `ServiceLifetime.Scoped`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EFCoreContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

I hope this will help you to resolve the issue.